# How can i create a text in the notifications bar?

Tags: android, text, statusbar, android-notifications

As you can see from this image i want to create which is inside the red circle. How can i create a text in the notifications bar? This is the image: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=23hu5xd&s=6

this is my notification

```
notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);

                notificationBuilder.setOngoing(true);
                notificationBuilder.setContentTitle("Battery Stats Informations");
                notificationBuilder.setContentText("Carica residua: " +level+"%" + " " + "Temperatura: " +temperature+ "°C");
                notificationBuilder.setTicker("Battery level " +level+ "%");
                notificationBuilder.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());
                notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon_small_not).setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());
                Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
                PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
                notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

                notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

                Notification not=notificationBuilder.build();

                mNotificationManager.notify(SIMPLE_NOTIFICATION_ID,not);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have N icons, one for each different "text" you want to show, and use the appropriate icon in the `Notification.Builder` `setSmallIcon()` call.

IOW, what you are seeing is less "text" than it is "an image that happens to have numbers on it".

Comment: so have i to do something like: `if (level = 100) {notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon_small_not)} if (level <= 90) {notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon_small_90)}` etc etc?

Comment: @David_D: That, or combine them into a `LevelListDrawable` and use the two-parameter version of `setSmallIcon()` that takes your `level` as the second parameter.

Comment: with the method i post 3 minutes ago works..but which is the name of the image in the blue circle?is it different?

Comment: @David_D: That is `setLargeIcon()`, for which you can supply a custom-rendered `Bitmap` if you wish.

Comment: and how can i create a bitmap image? i have only a png!

Comment: @David_D: Use `BitmapFactory` to load in the PNG file.